# Postback in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel

I have made a ToolBar usercontrol in a update panel. All buttons should work client side except a print button. I want to make this use the original postback.

`ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Toolbar2.PrintButton)`

However the button still doesn't refresh the page...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must set AutoPostBack to true? of the PrintButton that you have created

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the script manager to register a control as asynchronous, instead set the button as a trigger on the update panel itself, which you also can do via code.

HTH.

Comment: Well i tried that trough code, but it didn't help... However I "solved" my problem by just removing the update panel and do, what the update panel had todo trough jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

When you use RegisterAsyncPostBackControl you must also manually refresh the update panel using the Update() method.
http://geekswithblogs.net/lszk/archive/2011/08/08/playing-with-update-panels.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Triggers property of the UpdatePanel to register actions that trigger a full postback.

Add a PostBackTrigger object to that property, containig the ControlID of the control which needs to trigger a full postback.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    ...
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="myFullPostBackControlID" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```